# Let dplyr mutate use formula

Tags: r, dplyr, formula

I have a large dataset stored in a long dataframe. I would like to extract data on some variables and use a formula to generate new data. All the necessary information should be extracted from the formula. First, I want to use the information in the formula to filter the dataset for the according variables - I use the `all.vars()` function for that. I also rely on the `formula.tools` package, which is on CRAN. It is used for easy extraction of the left and right hand side of the equation (`lhs`and `rhs`, respectively).

```
library(dplyr)
library(reshape2)
library(formula.tools)

set.seed(100)

the_data <- data.frame(country = c(rep("USA", 9), rep("DEU", 9), rep("CHN", 9)),
                       year    = c(2000, 2010, 2020),
                       variable = c(rep("GDP", 3), rep("Population", 3), rep("Consumption", 3)),
                       value = rnorm(27, 100, 100))

add_variable <- function(df, equation){
  df <- filter(df, variable %in% all.vars(equation))

  df <- dcast(df, country + year ~ variable)

  df <- mutate_(df, rhs(equation))

  # code to keep only the newly generated column
  # ...

  df <- melt(df, id.vars = c("country", "year"))
}

result <- add_variable(the_data, GDPpC ~ GDP / Population)
```

The newly generated column should be named `GDPpC`, currently it is called `GDP/Population`. How can this be improved? In a final step I would like to also filter the data so that only the newly generated data is contained in the result, which can then be attached to the source dataframe via `rbind`.

Comment: Hard to tell what your question is

Comment: Thanks, you are right. I have tried to improve that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would that be a solution ?

```
add_variable <- function(df, equation){
      df <- filter(df, variable %in% all.vars(equation))
      orig_vars <- unique(df$variable)
      df <- dcast(df, country + year ~ variable)

      df <- mutate_(df, rhs(equation))
      colnames(df)[ncol(df)] <- as.character(lhs(equation))

      df <- melt(df, id.vars = c("country", "year"))
      df <- filter(df, !variable%in%orig_vars)
    }

    result <- add_variable(the_data, GDPpC ~ GDP / Population)
    result
  country year variable      value
1     CHN 2000    GDPpC 0.04885649
2     CHN 2010    GDPpC 2.62313658
3     CHN 2020    GDPpC 0.31685382
4     DEU 2000    GDPpC 0.80180998
5     DEU 2010    GDPpC 0.62642877
6     DEU 2020    GDPpC 0.97587188
7     USA 2000    GDPpC 0.26383912
8     USA 2010    GDPpC 1.01303516
9     USA 2020    GDPpC 0.69851501
```

Answer (score 0):

I wound up here many years later while looking for information on using a formula inside a `dplyr::mutate`, since I often find that to be much more concise and clear.  `dplyr` has of course grown and changed since 2016, including the fact that `transmute` is now deprecated.  But the good news is that if you're willing to use `formula.tools` the solution is very concise. as shown below.

```r
library(dplyr)

# reproducible play_data

set.seed(2020)
play_data <- 
  data.frame(
    a = runif(20, 0.01, .5),
    b = runif(20, 0.02, .5),
    c = runif(20, 0.03, .5),
    d = runif(20, 0.04, .5),
    e = runif(20,1,5),
    f = runif(20,10,50)
  )

my_formula <- newvariable ~ a * b^c / d * log(e) - f

require(formula.tools)

mutate_by_formula <- function(df, equation){
  df %>% transmute( !!lhs(equation) := !!rhs(equation) )
}

mutate_by_formula(play_data, my_formula)
#>    newvariable
#> 1    -25.80405
#> 2    -20.48974
#> 3    -37.87361
#> 4    -46.52231
#> 5    -19.88420
#> 6    -16.49153
#> 7    -37.25498
#> 8    -41.02025
#> 9    -31.88338
#> 10   -42.17896
#> 11   -30.75905
#> 12   -10.42447
#> 13   -25.84538
#> 14   -46.08206
#> 15   -13.51940
#> 16   -25.30124
#> 17   -19.80536
#> 18   -26.42881
#> 19   -38.02190
#> 20   -30.51113
```

As to OP's original example and specifics, it's slightly more complex since the data has to be shaped but the basic notion is the same.  The only twists are the `dcast` and the final `select` to remove variables that were used in the calculations.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(reshape2)
library(formula.tools)

set.seed(100)

the_data <- data.frame(country = c(rep("USA", 9), rep("DEU", 9), rep("CHN", 9)),
                       year    = c(2000, 2010, 2020),
                       variable = c(rep("GDP", 3), rep("Population", 3), rep("Consumption", 3)),
                       value = rnorm(27, 100, 100))

specific_function <- function(df, equation){
  df %>% 
    filter(variable %in% all.vars(equation)) %>%
    dcast(country + year ~ variable) %>%
    mutate(!!lhs(equation) := !!rhs(equation)) %>%
    select(-all.vars(equation)[2:length(all.vars(equation))])
}

specific_function(the_data, GDPpC ~ GDP / Population)
#>   country year      GDPpC
#> 1     CHN 2000 0.04885649
#> 2     CHN 2010 2.62313658
#> 3     CHN 2020 0.31685382
#> 4     DEU 2000 0.80180998
#> 5     DEU 2010 0.62642877
#> 6     DEU 2020 0.97587188
#> 7     USA 2000 0.26383912
#> 8     USA 2010 1.01303516
#> 9     USA 2020 0.69851501
```

<sup>Created on 2020-05-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>