# Optional argument conflicts with data frame in formula

Tags: r

I would like to design an optional argument called data in R function.

```
test = function(formula, data = NULL){
  print(data)
}
```

However, if formula uses a data frame called "data", it will conflict with the optional argument and be assigned as `NULL`. See the example below, nothing will be print.

```
data(ovarian)
data = ovarian
formula = Surv(data$futime,data$fustat)~data$ecog.ps
test(formula)
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish here. Would it not be better to have an abstract formula (i.e. variable names, rather than variables themselves) and then pass the data as an additional argument?

Comment: @JeroenColin Thanks, but I am not sure how to modify my codes with your suggestion. Can you   modify the codes directly?

Comment: You should never use `$` within formulas.

Comment: @Roland Why $ can not be used in formula?

Comment: Because it is very difficult to deal correctly with that in functions working with these formulas (usually model functions and functions which use the resulting models). It can and does often give surprising results. Anyway, your function prints `data`. Why are you surprised it prints NULL if you pass `data = NULL`? What is unexpected there?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I would like to see the result that data in formula rather than data in second argument is printed. Data in the second argument is an optional argument, so I hope it will not affect the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`data` within the function scope is always the `data` parameter. Your expected result is unreasonable and non-standard. You can do this:

```
test = function(formula, data = NULL){
  elementsformula <- all.names(formula)
  inds <- which(elementsformula == "$") #check for subsetting
  res <- if (length(inds) > 0) {
    #return each first element following subsetting
    mget(unique(elementsformula[inds + 1]), envir = parent.frame(n = 1))
  } else {
      data
  }
  if (is.list(res)) res else data
}

library(survival)
data(ovarian)
data = ovarian
formula = Surv(data$futime,data$fustat)~data$ecog.ps
test(formula)
#$data
#   futime fustat     age resid.ds rx ecog.ps
#1      59      1 72.3315        2  1       1
#2     115      1 74.4932        2  1       1
#3     156      1 66.4658        2  1       2
#4     421      0 53.3644        2  2       1
#5     431      1 50.3397        2  1       1
#6     448      0 56.4301        1  1       2
#7     464      1 56.9370        2  2       2
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It is a perfect solution to my weird problem.

Answer (score 0):

This seems a bit far-fetched, without any context, but I created a working example to add a column to a data.frame, using a formula provided.

I used the suggestions made in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37684283/let-dplyr-mutate-use-formula)

```
test = function(formula, data = NULL){

  data <- data %>% mutate_(formula.tools::rhs(formula))
  colnames(data)[ncol(data)] <- as.character(formula.tools::lhs(formula))
  data
}

# summing
test(c ~ a + b, data = df)

# pythagoras
test(c ~ sqrt(a^2 + b^2), data = df)
```

Comment: Thank you @Jeroen Colin. Let me think about it.